# Cannot associate tables in sequalize (node js + sequalize)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've got two tables that are structured like this:

FeedPost
id, text, likecount, commentcount

Comment
id, text, lkpfeedpostid

So there's a foreign key from comment to feedpost via lkpfeedpostid. So one FeedPost could have many Comment. I'm trying to set this up in sequalize so that when I do a FeedPost.findAll(), it pulls back the feed posts with all the comments.

Here's how I've set it up:

Model Definitions:

FeedPost:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('FeedPost', {
  ...
  ...
   }, {
    tableName: 'FeedPost',
    classMethods: {
      associate : function(models) {
        FeedPost.hasMany( Comment, { as: 'comments' });
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Comment:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Comment', {
  ...
  ...
   }, {
    tableName: 'Comment',
    classMethods: {
      associate : function(models) {
        Comment.belongsTo(FeedPost, { foreignKey: 'lkpfeedpostid'})
      },
    },
  });
};
```

I'm importing them like:

```
const FeedPost = sequelize.import('../models/FeedPost');
const Comment = sequelize.import('../models/Comment');
```

And passing them into an express router like:

```
app.use(feed(FeedPost, Comment));

module.exports = (FeedPost, Comment) => {
  const api = Router();

  api.get('/api/feed', (req, res) => {
    FeedPost.findAll( { include: [ {model: Comment, as: 'Comment' }]}).then(results => {
      res.json({results});
    });
}
```

I've tried tons of variations of this found in these links:

- http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#import
- http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/has-many.js~HasMany.html
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3273

And whenever I hit the route, I keep getting the error that says

`Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Comment is not associated to Feed!`

Answer (score 2):

I am going with that assumption that your sequelize version >=4.

`classMethods` and `instanceMethods` have  been removed. The changelog can be found here : [Sequelize V4 Breaking Changes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes)

From their [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongsto) you can refer the current method to specify associations.

FeedPost

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const FeedPost =  sequelize.define('FeedPost', {/*Attributes here*/});
    FeedPost.hasMany(Comment, { as: 'comments' })
};
```

Comment

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Comment =  sequelize.define('Comment', {/*Attributes here*/});
    Comment.BelongsTo(Comment, { foreignKey: 'lkpfeedpostid', targetKey: 'id' })
};
```

The following query should work:

```
FeedPost.findAll( { include: [ {model: Comment, as: 'comments' }]})
```